# Reusing directives for multiple modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to know what is the best way to reuse the same directive for multiple modules. In my mind i think directives are like DOM-modules, so the architecture of angular for this is a bit annoying of my point of view.

The way I'm doing it now is:

```
var mainapp = angular.module('MainApp');
mainapp.controller( ... );

var otherapp = angular.module('OtherApp');
otherapp.controller( ... );
```

And in other file i have my directive i want to use in this two controllers/modules

```
mainapp.directive('autoselect', function(){ ... });
```

But as you can see, I have to specify in what app I have to use it. If I want to use in both, do i have to copy twice the same code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can maintain a module that contains common (services, directives, values, constants etc.) and inject into each module.

```
angular.module('CommonApp',['OtherCommonModule1','OtherCommonModule2']).directive(..);

var mainapp = angular.module('MainApp', ['CommonApp']);
mainapp.controller( ... );

var otherapp = angular.module('OtherApp', ['CommonApp']);
otherapp.controller( ... );
```

Comment: you beat me to it! :)

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't have to specify which app/module you need to use a directive in.

Let me explain:

1. In angularJS, everything is a module. For example, MainApp, OtherApp and even the autoselect directive is a module.
2. Each module can 'depend' on one or more modules.

So, here's how I would design the solution:

```
angular.module('com.example.mydirective', [])
  .directive('autoselect', function() { ... });

angular.module('MainApp', ['com.example.mydirective']);
  .controller(...);

angular.module('OtherApp', ['com.example.mydirective']);
  .controller(...);
```

One thing I'd like to add: the square brackets that denote the dependency have a special significance.

```
angular.module('module-name', []); // this line tells angularJS to create a new module

angular.module('module-name'); // no brackets -- this asks angularjs to return a pre-existing module
```

Hope this helps